# Need help understanding where return value of function goes

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

I think I have a pretty big logic issue here. A function return value isn't recognized by another function. I am not quite sure where the value that is returned by DoStuff goes...why can't I access the value numArray?

It is my understanding that all values inside a function are local to that function...unless I use return, which SHOULD allow me to access that value.

So this code is simply in an external js file...what you see is the only thing in it. My big question is when I return numArray...where does that value go?

```js
function doStuff(){

    //document.write("We are testing document writing now!");

    let numArray;
    let sumArray;
    let start = parseInt(prompt("Enter a small number"));
    let end = parseInt(prompt("Enter a larger number"));

    if (start > end){
        alert("Error: first int greater than last!")
    } else {
        let arraySize = end - start;
        numArray = [start];
        for (let x = start + 1; x <= end; ++x){
            numArray.push(x);
        } 
        console.log(numArray);    
        return numArray;  
    }
}

function addArray(numArray) {
    console.log(numArray);
}
```

```html
<form> <input type="button" value="Click Me to generate an array of numbers!" onclick="doStuff()"/> <input type="button" value="Click me to add the array numbers" onclick="addArray()"/> </form>
```

Console is telling me that numArray is undefined when I try to log it. I am needing to get the array (numArray) and use the data in the array to do some more things to them. Both functions are "called" by onclick buttons on a webpage (so I have to click the DoStuff button before the addArray button).

Comment: Where do you call `addArray`? Is that the functions that's printing `undefined`? Donyoy ever use the return of `DoStuff`?

Comment: let numArray is a nested local variable inside a function. If you call doStuff and return numArray, you have to save that variable somewhere. Please add the code where you call both addArray and doStuff :)

Comment: just fixed that... while the function is never being called, to begin with.

Comment: And `DoStuff` doesn't return anything explicitly if `start > last`.

Comment: @Martin, they are called, "_Both functions are "called" by onclick button_" ...

Comment: DoStuff and addArray are called when I click a button on the webpage. So....

<form>
 <input type="button" value="Click Me to generate an array of numbers!" 
          onclick="DoStuff()"/>
 <input type="button" value="Click me to add the array numbers" 
         onclick="addArray()"/>
</form>

Comment: @Bulletbutter If that's how you're calling `addArray`, you're never passing any data to it, so `numArray` will be undefined. I think this is more of a misunderstanding of how function, parameters, and return values work. `numArray` in `addArray` doesn't have a value simply because you returned a variable with the same name in another function.

Comment: `return` returns the value to the caller of the function. In this case, it is received in the inline handler, but it is not used, i.e. not assigned to any variable, and hence it's thrown away.

Comment: `var numArray = [];` would need to be defined in the global scope - without passing it as parameter into function `addArray()` and without redefining it in function `doStuff()`... since there is no return value assignment, it will be logged, but the return value will be discarded.

Comment: I added some lines, but the problem really is just a missing assignment of the result, so no biggie ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call addArray function from DoStuff function and pass numArray as a parameter to it

```
function DoStuff() {

let numArray;
let sumArray;
let start = 1;
let end = 5;

if (start > end){
    alert("Error: first int greater than last!")
}
else {
    let arraySize = end - start;
    numArray = [start];
    for (let x = start + 1; x <= end; ++x){
        numArray.push(x);
    }    
}
addArray(numArray)
}

function addArray(numArray){
        console.log(numArray); 
}
```

Comment: I can make this work. I just loose the ability to not make it happen. Doing it this way forces it to occur when the original idea was to only make it happen when I pressed the button on the webpage.

Comment: I have a solution that can call the two functions separately .. even if you don't accept my answer, give it a try, you might achieve your goal that way :)

Comment: Bulletbutter you can call the DoStuff function on click of the button

Answer (score 2):

> all values inside a function are local to that function...unless I use
>   return

Well, this is... partially true. First part is true and there is no "unless". `return` statement is just pointing to the value that is, well, returned by a function. It doesn't mean that this variable is now global. Value in `return` is kind of "value of function" and you must store it in a variable if you want to use it later, as you can see in others' answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your main js file that contains those onclick functions, you need to have a global variable to store your numArray after you call doStuff function.

Something like this:

```
let globalNumArray

// on click button doStuff
function (){
    globalNumArray = doStuff()
}

// on click button addArray
function() {
    addArray(globalNumArray)
}
```

> My big question is when I return numArray...where does that value go?

The return value goes to where you called that particular function.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
The reason why global variables are discouraged in js is, because all code has a single global namespace, where javascript has implied global variables automatically (like variables which are not explicitly declared in local scope are automatically added to global namespace). Relying **too much** on global variables **can** result in some collisions between scripts on the same page. This doesn't mean, that you mustn't use global variables but you shouln't use them light-mindedly. If you need  a variable to be accessable after the function has finished, your choices are limited, so either use a global variable or pass the variable to the function you need it in.

You just need to save the result of doStuff and then access that variable in addArray:

```js
var result
function doStuff() {

  //document.write("We are testing document writing now!");

  let numArray;
  let sumArray;
  let start = parseInt(prompt("Enter a small number"));
  let end = parseInt(prompt("Enter a larger number"));

  if (start > end) {
    alert("Error: first int greater than last!")
  } else {
    let arraySize = end - start;
    numArray = [start];
    for (let x = start + 1; x <= end; ++x) {
      numArray.push(x);
    }
    result = numArray; // save result for later (has to be a global scope)
  }
}

function addArray() { // you defined this without an input in your form, so stick to that
  if (result) // check if value exists
    console.log(result);
  else
    console.log("Please enter the numbers boundaries first first.");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Click Me to generate an array of numbers!" onclick="doStuff()" />
  <input type="button" value="Click me to add the array numbers" onclick="addArray()" />
</form>
```

Comment: I've always read that I should avoid global variables at all costs, so I am trying to do it without using global variables.

Comment: So you don't want a global variable but you want to call a function that needs one? I can't wrap my head around it... I mean this works and uses one global variable, you'll have to decide whether you want the function to work as you intended or work kind of right but without your two buttons without a global variable

Comment: I added an explanation on the usage of global variables :)

Comment: My issue was not realizing that I couldn't use the return value of DoStuff() the way I was wanting to. I understand that using the global variable will work...I just didn't understand why until all these kind people responded. 

I wasn't necessarily looking for modified code as an answer (grateful for it however), but instead an answer as to why numArray was showing undefined in my incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

**doStuff()** is returning a value, so use the return of this function as a variable. We can assign this returned value to another variable or can use directly within expression. So call dostuff() to get the returned value.

```js
function doStuff(){

    //document.write("We are testing document writing now!");

    let numArray;
    let sumArray;
    let start = parseInt(prompt("Enter a small number"));
    let end = parseInt(prompt("Enter a larger number"));

    if (start > end){
        alert("Error: first int greater than last!")
    } else {
        let arraySize = end - start;
        numArray = [start];
        for (let x = start + 1; x <= end; ++x){
            numArray.push(x);
        } 
        console.log(numArray);    
        return numArray;  
    }
}

 console.log('HERE IS ARRAY: '+doStuff());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple things I think could help you out:

1) Split your code. doStuff, prompts the user for input, but it also generates an array containing values from min-max. You should have a separate function that generates an array from min to max. Splitting it up will make it easier to identify a problem.

2) A few solutions suggest a global variable this can be dangerous. When
you must share state limit its scope to only what needs to access that state.

3) Make your interfaces consistent. You should not return a value one instance and nothing in another. If there is an error make sure you are consistent with how you notify the caller.

```js
function buildArray(start, end) {
  let arr = [];

  if (start > end) {
    // There are a lot ways to deal with this
    // But you want a consistent interface for letting
    // the caller no that start < end
    throw {
     message: 'Start can\'t be bigger than end',
    };
  }
  
  for (let x = start; x <= end; x++) {
    arr.push(x);
  }
  
  return arr; 
}

// encapsulate the variable numArray, so that it is only accessible
// to the methods that need it
var numArrayModule = (function(){
   let numArray = [];
   
   return {
     doStuff: function(){
        let start = parseInt(prompt("Enter a small number"));
        let end = parseInt(prompt("Enter a larger number"));
        try {
          numArray = buildArray(start, end);
        } catch(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
     },
     addArray: function(){
        console.log(numArray);
     },
   }

}());
// You may use these as onClick handlers as well.
numArrayModule.doStuff();
numArrayModule.addArray();
```